# How to display hourly averaged time data on a line chart?

Tags: charts, time, timeline

Assume that I have data collected every minute.
If I want to display that data on a line chart with data averaged to every hour.

**Is it assumed that a label on the horizontal axis is the measurement from the beginning of that hour to the start of the next hour**?
Or should the data point be the average of that hour +/- 30 minutes?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is correct:

> a label on the horizontal axis is the measurement from the beginning of that hour to the start of the next hour

Take your first two labels for example. The data point for 14:00 should encompass activity that took place during the **14th hour**, i.e. the time from 14:00 to 14:59.

It's easier to wrap your mind around it if you think of a history timeline:
[image: timeline]

The event that happened within the year of 1964 had to have happened from Jan 1 - Dec 31, 1964.

Image source: https://sintoamerica.com/history/sai-history-timeline/

Comment: Excellent example, thanks so much!